# Which file configures the desktop envionments that are available to log into on my system?

Tags: 18.04, login, desktop-environments

Where can I find all the desktop environments I can log into (which appear to choose from at login)?

I mean, where are these login options configured for Ubuntu to know the names for each desktop environment? I want to be able to investigate their configuration files/process names etc.

Comment: I find the question quite confusing because it contains more than one issue. This site prefers addressing single issues per question.

Comment: Sorry, I am editing.

Comment: What do you want to know? What you mean with "what is what"? Question is decidedly unclear. Different things are to be found on different places in your system, so you will need to be more specific and perhaps tell us about the real problem you want to solve.

Comment: @vanadium I first mentioned my initial problem, which is login loop with "Ubuntu" desktop environment (DE). See DK Bose's comment on that. So I edited. I realized that I don't know what "Ubuntu" DE is. Is it GNOME (with 18.04) or Unity (16.04) or actually a "Ubuntu" DE? To find it out (and there are more DEs available at login), I can look into a config file, where they are mentioned/listed. What does that label "Ubuntu" stand for? I did some research and couldn't find, where on Ubuntu all DEs are listed. Because, I expect that every label is linked to a specific comm./proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Ubuntu 16.04 (and possibly others as well), the list of sessions/login options will be in the directory `/usr/share/xsessions/` (one file per option).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.